# how to select a rectangle (to crop to) in gimp?

Tags: gimp, crop

How can I select a rectangle and crop to it in gimp?

I opened an image.  The rectangle selection tool is apparently selected. The mouse cursor consisted of a cross-hairs, a no-entry sign, and a double-lined square.  I could not select anything.

The status bar says "Click-drag to subtract from the current selection".  So I guess it is in some weird mode.  But I can not work out how to get it out of this mode, and into a mode where I can perform the extremely basic task of selecting a rectangle.

Comment: You're confusing Selection & Crop. https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tutorial-quickie-crop.html

Answer (score 0):

See screenshot below: In the Tool Options, next to "Mode" click on the first button which says "Replace the current selection". This is the default selection mode.

Once you have made a selection, you can cut it, copy it, paste as a new layer, etc. If you want to crop an image, use the Crop Tool instead.  If you have made a selection instead, you can also do *Image > Crop to Selection*

[image]